# How to 'renew' fixed Azure Website Production Slot?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

If I have a 'Standard' App Service Plan with 5 websites and two instances.

One website is behaving badly (restarting randomly*) and displaying weirdly (eg: portal > Monitor never shows 'Response Time' data; Daas 'Diagnose' Now' just errors etc.)

This website has been running for two years. Various experiments have been tried (installing things like New Relic, then 'removing' them) so I'm thinking it's time for a fresh start because I'm worried that all these old settings are confusing things and causing issues: I want to try and move this web site off it's existing 'settings' to a clean slate

I tried:

1. Created new deployment slot (choosing "Don't clone configuration from an existing slot" (in the hope of losing old settings and having a clean start). Slot is called newstage).
2. Confirmed that newstage runs and has good monitor (ResponseTime is back. No more 'could not retrieve metrics' errors in portal)
3. Swapped newstage with live
4. Confirmed that experiment failed. The swapped deployment has inherited all the old problems.

My Question is: It looks like new deployment slots are created anew and work perfectly. Apart from deleting the webapp and re-creating it (I can't do this) is there any way I can make the fixed 'Live' slot as perfect as the new deployment slots?

*`INFO] Terminating RD000Dabc. 11/5/2015 3:25:32 PM vs (now) 11/5/2015 3:25:47 PM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing should result in a very clean state after you swap the clean slot into production. All of the files are swapped, so file-wise, there is nothing left from before.

The only thing that could remain is if you have any App Settings marked as 'slot setting' (it's a checkbox in the Preview Portal).

There is also a slim possibility that something got corrupted at a level that you can't control. Can you share your site name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate.

Comment: There aren't any slot settings. The site is 'adv001' if your team could take a look that would great.

Comment: Is the site in a bad state now? From what I can see, it seems healthy. Both https://adv001.azurewebsites.net/ and the scm site (https://adv001.scm.azurewebsites.net/) look normal. Can you share a specific time (UTC preferably) during which you have run into issues?

Comment: There's no 'Response Time' ever being reported (the other websites and slots do report this metric). Other than that it's running ok atm. I'll watch it closely for errors and get back to you. I do feel re-assured you say it's healthy - thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly where you are looking for this response time? Is this on https://manage.windowsazure.com/ or on https://portal.azure.com/, and where specifical within that site are you looking?

Comment: manage.windowsazure.com > Monitor > 'Response Time' for adv001.  I've just removed the metric and there's no option to add it any more so maybe it's been dropped? I'm happy to let it go, so don't feel you need to look into it. If you say it all looks healthy and I can see no errors atm I'll leave it and get back to checking my code as a source of issues. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I do see a metric called `AverageResponseTime` in there. Maybe that's what it was? In any case, makes sense to leave this alone if everything looks healthy.